# Firebase and Google Cloud Storage API

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

So okay, first of all I am completely new to Google Cloud Storage and I am looking for someone to answer few questions.

The thing is, I was using Firebase on a lot of projects and Firebase Storage too, but this is the first time I need to use Google Cloud Storage.

To explain:
We have an app that is using Firebase as a "backend" for authentication and saving some data. The client requested that we need Google Cloud Storage for saving to storage, since they already have an account for that and that they don't need to update Firebase plan.

I noticed Google Cloud Storage doesn't offer any mobile SDK so we can use to communicate to storage, so do we need to create custom API for communication?
I saw that there is a way to add additional buckets to existing Firebase projects, would that work with Firebase? Or is there a way we can add Firebase bucket to Google Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: Firebase Storage is Cloud Storage. You have access to the same buckets, we just provide a nice mobile experience :)

Import their Cloud project to Firebase, and then import whatever buckets you want to use into the Firebase Console.

Then you can add the appropriate permissions to those buckets, and use the Firebase SDK to access your bucket.

Check out our blog post that details this a little more: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/multiplying-power-firebase-storage.html

Comment: Thanks for answering this!
Since they purchased Google Cloud Storage, will we still need to upgrade project plan to Blaze to add additional buckets?

Comment: Yes, though they won't get charged anything extra for using Firebase Storage--it basically just links the billing account from the Cloud Project to the Firebase Project.

Comment: Thank you for your time and help!